# How to create a button for each item of a select2 list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

I need to create a button (view) next to each list item in a select2 component during loading.
I didn't find anything on the web that could help me.
Does anyone know how to do it?

```
$("#MySelect2").select2({
    tags: "true",
    createTag: function () {
        // Dessabilita a inserção quando Enter for pressionada
        return null;
    },
    placeholder: "Selecione uma opção",
    allowClear: false,
    width: '100%',
    dropdownParent: genericModal,
    language: {
        noResults: function () {
            return "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
        }
    }
});

<div class="col-md-4">
    <label asp-for="ParentescoTipoId" class="control-label">Tipo de Parentesco</label>
    <select asp-for="ParentescoTipoId" asp-items="Model.ParentescosTipos" id = "MySelect2" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control sel-pessoa-fisica-parentesco-parentesco-tipo" style="position: fixed !important;"><option value=""></option></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="ParentescoTipoId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.
You have to use templateResult.
So then it's possible to add a button to each element.
For uniqueness I added a data-id attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    minimumInputLength: -1,
    placeholder: 'Search',
    data: [{
      id: 1,
      text: "First"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: "Second"
    }],
    templateResult: function(data) {
      var $result = $("<span></span>");
      console.log('data', data.id);
      $result.text(data.text);
      $result.append('<button data-id="' + data.id + '" class="btn">' + data.text + '</button>');
      return $result;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  float:right;
}

.js-example-basic-single {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just one question: And if I were to create a click event, what would it be like? @Bernhard Beatus

Comment: I made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/ytLhbzmc/5/