# Can I add a custom button to each entry in a Select2 "results" dropdown?

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm currently building a UI component for creating custom time window ranges. my project already uses Select2 version `4.0.13` for various other elements, so I'm building this on the "[dynamic option creation](https://select2.org/tagging)" feature here.

the gist of my idea is as follows:

- allow the user to select from any existing entry - which will populate the "start" and "end" hour input fields.
- allow the user to enter a custom "start" or "end" hour - which will update the select list to show "Custom Window".
- allow the user to provide a new name to save the currently set "start" and "end" hour values - this is where Select2 "tags" come into play.
- allow the user to delete a previously saved time window entry - this is where I'm having trouble..

my current WIP UI looks as follows:

[image: WIP UI controls]

the crux of the issue here, is that I cannot figure out how to get a custom event handler bound to the custom `<button>` element that I'm adding to each option.. no matter what I try, Select2 always takes a click anywhere on the option item as "selecting that option", even if the mouse click occurs on the custom button that I've added.

my markup is being generated on page load, and comes out with the following bare minimum structure:

```html
<select title="Select your time window here, enter a name to create a new entry." name="time_window_name">
  <option class="internal-option"></option>
  <option value="custom" disabled="disabled" class="internal-option">Custom Window</option>
</select>
```

- the empty option here is used by Select2 as a placeholder for "no selection".
- the "Custom Window" option is used by my logic to show when either a "start" or "end" time input field has a value (not shown here).

when a new `<option>` is added to the source `<select>` element, it appears in the list as per the following two examples:

```html
<select title="Select your time window here, enter a name to create a new entry." name="time_window_name">
  [ snip... ]
  <option value="7,8">Morning Rush</option>
  <option value="16,17">Evening Rush</option>
</select>
```

- where the option's `value` refers to `startHour,endHour`.

I'm initialising Select2 with the following config:

```js
{
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: "no filter",
  tags: true,
  createTag: createTagHandler,
  templateResult: templateResultHandler,
}
```

where `createTagHandler` just does some basic checks (valid name, at least start or end time, etc) and `templateResultHandler` modifies the rendered select result entries as follows:

```js
function templateResultHandler(state) {
    if (!state.id || ["custom"].includes(state.id)) {
        return state.text;
    }

    const item = $("<div>", {
        class: "select2-result-item d-flex align-items-center",
    });
    $("<span>", {
        class: "select2-result-item__text",
        text: state.text,
    }).appendTo(item);

    const deleteButton = $("<button>", {
        type: "button",
        class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm ms-auto",
    }).appendTo(item);
    $("<i>", {
        class: "fa fa-trash",
    }).appendTo(deleteButton);

    return item;
}
```

- the `select2-result-item` classes seen here were suggested by other resources that I've found online, not sure if they are helping or not.

---

Similar questions:

I have seen a [virtually identical SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666853/how-to-create-a-button-for-each-item-of-a-select2-list), but the only answer doesn't cover attaching any click handlers, and [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/ytLhbzmc/5/) linked in response to the question owner querying that point uses Select2 version `3.5.2` (even though the answer snippet shows a CDN URL for `4.1.0-rc.0`). I have tried upgrading that JSFiddle to use version `4.0.13` and I get the exact same behaviour as my local project.

I thought I had found a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080305/16269129), but alas this only works when clicking the custom "delete" button for an entry that is NOT already selected... if it is, then neither the `select2:selecting` nor the `select2:select` events are fired.

Comment: FWIW: as per my last question edit, I have made some decent progress with this, but I have not solved all the little niggles.. in the meantime, I'm opting to simply not show a "delete" button for the currently selected option, as this is **currently** the only condition that would skip over my handler logic. this feels too hacky for my liking though, it will suffice for now, but I would rather have a more definitive solution in the long term.

Comment: to make things even more interesting, within the `templateResult` handler, the `state` object it receives seems to keep `selected` as `true` once an item has been selected once, even if the selection is cleared or another option is selected (not using multi-select). that may be a bug in Select2 though.. I'm still digging.